# .getUsername() not functioning properly within Workspace account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

A two part question:

1. The script below is intended to watch for edits in column 6 of a specific sheet and when triggered, execute the three parts of the script (marked A-C below). All works properly for me as the owner of the sheet within a Workspace account. For other users who edit the sheet, part A works properly, but not B or C. All users are part of the same Workspace account.
2. As an alternative to watching just Col 6, any suggestions as to how I could rewrite the script to record the location of the most recently edited cell on a given row?

Thank you.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "STATUS" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 6 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 6 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 2000
     ) {
       var range = e.range;
       var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("STATUS");
       
    //A: on modified row, copy live status to permanent
       status.getRange(range.getRow() , 11).copyTo(status.getRange(range.getRow() , 7), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
       
    //B: set time & date modified
       status.getRange(range.getRow() , 8).setValue(new Date());
       
    //C: set user who last modified ID column
       status.getRange(range.getRow() , 9).setValue(Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername());
       
       }
    else
    { return; }
   }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. The script is working fine disregarding whether the editing user is the owner or not. Can you please provide more details about `part A works properly, but not B or C`? Are you getting any error? Have you checked where does the script stop executing (doing some [logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#logging), going to [debugger mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints), etc)?

Answer (score 1):

With getEffectiveUser() you get the user under whose authority the script is running, change this to getActiveUser(). See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session). To get the column & row of the onEdit range try this:

- e.range.getRow()
- e.range.getColumn()

Answer (score 0):

In a [simple `onEdit()` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite), [`Session.getEffectiveUser()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) is equivalent to [`Session.getActiveUser()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser), which states:

> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger...

You should be able to generalize "email address" to username or any other personally identifiable information. That kind of information requires authorization.

The only way to make this work would be to have your other users authorize this script first.

If you don't want the trigger to be restricted to edits in Column 6, remove that condition from your if statement.

```
// These lines specify column 6
e.range.columnStart == 6 &&
e.range.columnEnd == 6 &&
```